# IQueryable return type with Lambda statements

Tags: c#, silverlight, lambda, iqueryable, return-type

i am facing problem with the return type for this function and not really getting anywhere near solving can someone help me with this?

here goes the function,

```
public IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>> GetDiscussion_categoriesWithBoards()
{
    return GetDiscussion_categories().Select(c =>
        new
        {
            Category = c,
            Boards = GetDiscussion_boardsByCategory(c.ID).ToList()
        }).ToDictionary(i => i.Category, i => i.Boards.ToList());
}
```

this is the other function that works which is used in the above function that doen't work,

```
public IQueryable<discussion_board> GetDiscussion_boardsByCategory(int CategoryID)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.discussion_boards.Where(e => e.CategoryID == CategoryID);
}
public IQueryable<discussion_category> GetDiscussion_categories()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.discussion_categories;
}
```

I need this to be the return type:

```
IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>>
```

thank you friends!

Comment: What's is the return type of GetDiscussion_categories?

Comment: its IQueryable<discussion_board> John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're calling [ToDictionary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx), your method returns a `Dictionary<>`, not an `IQueryable<>`:

```
public Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>
GetDiscussion_categoriesWithBoards()
{
    // ...
}
```

If you absolutely want to return an `IQueryable<>` you can write something like:

```
public IQueryable<Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>>
GetDiscussion_categoriesWithBoards()
{
    return new[] {
        GetDiscussion_categories().Select(c => new {
            Category = c,
            Boards = GetDiscussion_boardsByCategory(c.ID).ToList()
        }).ToDictionary(i => i.Category, i => i.Boards.ToList())
    }.AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type will be:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>
```

as the return type of ToDictionary is Dictionary object and not a Iqueryable of Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this function will return:

```
Dictionary<Category, List<Board>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer :)

```
public IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>> GetDiscussion_categoriesWithBoards()
{
    return (GetDiscussion_categories().Select(c =>
        new
        {
            Category = c,
            Boards = GetDiscussion_boardsByCategory(c.ID).ToList()
        }).ToDictionary(i => i.Category, i => i.Boards.ToList())).AsQueryable() as IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<discussion_category, List<discussion_board>>>;
}
```

this is the solution :)

thank you for all your help your questions and answers lead me to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking what is the return type of the lambda? It looks to be a `Dictionary<Category,List<Board>>`